# Uncertain how to properly filter when certain fields do not always exist

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to filter based on a field that, on some objects, does not exist. I was under the impression that ES would match objects that don't have that field.

Ultimately, I am trying to filter as such:

- Field A will always exist, and should match on any of tags 1,2,3
- When it exists, either Field B or C must match any of tags 5,6,7
- When it exists, Field B must match any of tags 10, 11, 12
- When it exists, Field B or C must NOT have any of tags 15, 16, 18.

In this case, all my tags are strings. In addition, fields B and C are inside of another. I am uncertain if that matters.

Essentially, my object is:

```
{ a: ["some", "tags", "here"],
    X : { 
        B: ["more", "tags", "here"],
        C: ["even", "more", "here"]
    }
}
```

I am trying to essentially build a whitelist and blacklist filtering system.

However, when filtering this way, I do not get any results that do not contain the field.

How do I properly format this filter?

Answer (score 4):

Elasticsearch treats a null or non-existing field as not matching a query/filter on that field, so those results will not be returned by a standard query/filter. However, it is possible to set up a query that accomplishes what you are wanting, if I'm understanding you correctly. You can use a combination of `"or"`, `"not"`, and `"exist"` filters. I'll show you the basic idea with a few examples.

First, create an index and add some docs, with various fields missing from various docs:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test_index"

curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test_index/docs/1" -d'
{ 
    "a": ["some", "tags", "here"],
    "X" : { 
        "B": ["more", "tags", "here"],
        "C": ["even", "more", "here"]
    }
}'

curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test_index/docs/2" -d'
{ 
    "a": ["some", "tags", "here"]
}'

curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test_index/docs/3" -d'
{ 
    "a": ["some", "tags", "here"],
    "X" : { 
        "B": ["more", "tags", "here"]
    }
}'

curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test_index/docs/4" -d'
{ 
    "a": ["some", "tags", "here"],
    "X" : { 
        "C": ["even", "more", "here"]
    }
}'
```

If I want to retrieve the docs that contain the field `"X.B"` (with any value), I can use the following query:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test_index/docs/_search" -d'
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}
         },
         "filter": {
             "exists": {
                "field": "X.B"
             }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

This will return docs `"1"` and `"3"`.

On the other hand, if I want to return only the docs that do NOT have the field `"X.B"`, then I can use this query:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test_index/docs/_search" -d'
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}
         },
         "filter": {
            "not": {
               "filter": {
                  "exists": {
                     "field": "X.B"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

This returns docs `"2"` and `"4"`.

Now, if I want to return docs that either do not have the field `"X.B"`, or that field matches the term `"here"`, you can use an `"or"` filter as follows:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test_index/docs/_search" -d'
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}
         },
         "filter": {
            "or": [
               {
                  "term": { "X.B" : "here" }
               },
               {
                  "not": {
                     "filter": {
                        "exists": {
                           "field": "X.B"
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

In this case all four docs are returned, because they all match one of the two possible conditions.

This doesn't completely satisfy your use-case, but it should be enough to get you started.

Here is a runnable example you can play with (you will need ES installed and running at localhost:9200, or supply another endpoint): 
http://sense.qbox.io/gist/f1a644db97c89996f2b44f49793a2c76bae3155c

Comment: Curiously enough, I [followed your example](http://sense.qbox.io/gist/8f7369e7991db56f7b1592f11245cb8bf6dc933f) and find that when I insert a test document into a new index, my filter is filtering out a particular document based on my headline rule, however when I run it against my existing index, it returns bad data. It's starting to look like something may be wrong with my index.

Comment: [After adding my index settings](http://sense.qbox.io/gist/a73c74e71df4aca6c58283bca1cde6e6071644df), it appears as though something in my settings is at fault, not something in the logic.

Comment: And so what is the problem, I don't understand? You want the document to be returned, or you don't?

Comment: In this case, I want the document to not be returned -- when running with the first link, on a fresh index without any custom settings, it works fine. On the second link, with the settings that the index is setup with, it returns the result but it should not.

Comment: Take a look at this one: http://sense.qbox.io/gist/f4b493662a61e265c0c8b7ce39ca35d1fce52129.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not what you think it is. Or at least, there is another problem too. The difference you are seeing is due to how `"relatedProfiles"` is being analyzed.

Look at this gist: http://sense.qbox.io/gist/eec5dc038167ddd5d845a8ea8413a065f6e63f8f. I've defined the index in two different ways, the first (`testfeed1`) implicitly, and the second (`testfeed2`) with your explicit mapping. It's instructive to remove all but the first part of your query and run it against each index:

When I build the index the first way (no explicit mapping), and then search with only the filter on `"relatedProfiles" : ["LinkedIn/4505"]`, I don't get a result:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/testfeed1/feedItem/_search" -d'
{
   "query": {
      "match_all": {}
   },
   "filter": {
      "terms": {
         "relatedProfiles": [
            "LinkedIn/4505"
         ]
      }
   }
}'
```

...

```
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 2,
      "successful": 2,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 0,
      "max_score": null,
      "hits": []
   }
}
```

When I build the index the second way, with an explicit mapping (in which `"relatedProfiles"` is set to `"index": "not_analyzed"`), and then do the same search, I *do* get a result:

```
POST /testfeed2/feedItem/_search
{
   "query": {
      "match_all": {}
   },
   "filter": {
      "terms": {
         "relatedProfiles": [
            "LinkedIn/4505"
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

...

```
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 2,
      "successful": 2,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "testfeed2",
            "_type": "feedItem",
            "_id": "Metabase/16411941826",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "source": "Metabase/16411941826",
               "relatedProfiles": [
                  "LinkedIn/4505",
                  "Facebook/113470526913",
                  "CrunchBase/company/scholastic"
               ],
               "timestamp": "2014-01-08T00:49:35-05:00",
               "type": "News",
               "content": {
                  "title": "Opening doors for children, teachers",
                  "description": "class became published authors, chosen to put together the Florida section of “Fifty Great States Scrapbook,” published by Scholastic Books. Their book signing was at Barnes & Noble. “I saw an advertisement in the instructor magazine and decided to",
                  "url": "http://ct.moreover.com/ct?haid=8437fcfcdbaa900a138916017501692f42b5c333349b4&co=f000000011632s-1177024037&u1=SET&u2=56637",
                  "source": "St Augustine Herald"
               },
               "language": "en"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

The difference is in how the `"relatedProfiles"` field is analyzed. In the second case, it isn't analyzed at all, so `"LinkedIn/4505"` matches exactly, and the result is returned. In the first case, though, since no analyzer is specified the standard analyzer is used. And so the tokens end up being `"linkedin"` and `"4505"` (as you can see if you search for those tokens, like line 34 of the gist). Since we are using a terms filter in the above query, no analysis is done on the filter terms text, and "LinkedIn/4505" doesn't match any tokens, so no results are returned.

Make sense?